# Getting null query output after using QueryEntity

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have written following query entity for my database. I provide this file to ignite server node for index mapping. Loading part of data is done through ignite client node.

```js
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        
 <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
 <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
          
                <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
         <property name="name" value="warehouse_cache"/>   
      <property name="backups" value="0"/>
      <property name="copyOnRead" value="true"/>
      <property name="memoryMode" value="ONHEAP_TIERED"/>
      <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/> 
   
    <!-- Configure query entities -->
   <property name="queryEntities">
    <list>
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
      <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long"/>
      <property name="valueType" value="schema.warehouse"/>

      <property name="fields">
       <map>
        <entry key="w_id" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <entry key="w_name" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_street_1" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_street_2" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_city" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_state" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_zip" value="java.lang.String"/>
        <entry key="w_tax" value="java.lang.Double"/>
        <entry key="w_ytd" value="java.lang.Double"/>
        
       </map>
      </property>

      <property name="indexes">
       <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
         <constructor-arg value="w_id"/>
        </bean>
       </list>
      </property>
     </bean>
    </list>
   </property>  
         </bean>
            
           
            </list>
    </property>
 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

All entries of this warehouse table gets loaded correctly(verified using **ignitevisorcmd.sh**). For this query entity I have created jar file of package schema, which contains warehouse class. I kept this jar file in libs folder in apache ignite installation path. When I run query against this warehouse table, I am getting null output. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value type in configuration looks suspicious:

```
<property name="valueType" value="schema.warehouse"/>
```

Make sure that this value is correct value class name. Also what query are you executing?

Comment: I have added warehouse.java containing class warehouse to package schema. Thats why I wrote schema.warehouse. Query I am executing is `SELECT * from warehouse w WHERE w.w_id = 1` and entry corresponding to w_id = 1 is present in warehouse cache.